# ZF2 CurrencyFormat on Default locale not working

Tags: locale, zend-framework2, number-formatting

In my application I use serval languages. I'n my module.php I set the locale of a user by the follow methode:

```
$translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
$translator ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
            ->setFallbackLocale($this->setDomainLocale());
```

There are running server domain.tdl's on this application (different languages) so I use a function in my fallback to set the fallback locale per domain, anyway...

I want to make use of currencyFormat but I don't get it work to use it with the locale by user. I tried the code below with and without '\Locale::getDefault())';
A number like '1509053' and should be returned as '€ 1.509.053.00' or ',' depends on locale, I get just '€ 1509053.00'.

```
$this->plugin("currencyformat")->setCurrencyCode("EUR")->setLocale(\Locale::getDefault());
```

output of \Locale::getDefault())

```
string(11) "en_US_POSIX"
```

output of module.php $translator

```
   class Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator#193 (8) { protected $messages => array(0) { } 
protected $files => array(0) { } protected $patterns => array(1) { 'default' => array(1) { [0] => array(3) { 'type' => string(7) "gettext" 'baseDir' => string(119) "..../module/.../config/../language" 'pattern' => string(5) "%s.mo" } } } protected $remote => array(0) { } protected $locale => string(35) "nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" protected $fallbackLocale => string(5) "nl_NL" protected $cache => NULL protected $pluginManager => NULL }
```

Hope someone can put me in the right direction :) Thnx

Comment: This is just an assumption, but the error may be inside the `Locale` that is set. It should not be `en_US_POSIX` but rather `en_US`. Try setting the locale manually and not by `acceptFromHttp`

Comment: hmm.. If I set both (http|fallback) to nl_NL the default output is still 'en_US_POSIX'. When I set nl_NL 'hard' in the currency ->setLocale() it works like suposed

Comment: OK, I think I figure it out. I thought, by setting the translate Locale we set automatically the Locale::getDefault() aswel. This seems not right and is need to set the locale for this function aswel by Locale::setDefault();

Comment: If you found a working solution, you might as well post an answer to your question and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use the function '\Locale::getDefault();' we need to set first '\Locale::setDefault(language_code);' $translate->setLocale doesn't set Locale::getDefault();.

Comment: That is right. $translate->setLocale() (or, any $component->setLocale()), will always just set a fixed locale for that specific component/instance.